# Can a Super-Earth have a large moon?

Tags: space, habitability

I'm writing about a Super-Earth which is habitable and has a large moon, but I want to get one thing out of the way: can a Super-Earth have a large moon?

Wouldn't the Super-Earth pull on the moon, making it crash into the planet, which is a definite no-no for habitability?

Comment: Whether or not the moon would be stable depends on where the planet's roche-limit and/or hill-sphere are, which you can calculate if you know the proportions of your planet and moon, i.e. how massive/dens it is. Though generally speaking, just because the planet is heavier than earth, doesn't mean it's unable to have a moon, so it could have one.

Comment: I heard from somewhere on this website that super earths cant have moons guess thy were wrong eh

Comment: as far as i know, super-earths can have moons. In case you want to calculate all that stuff yourself, or want to know about other aspects of building fictional solar-systems and planets, [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/@Artifexian/videos) is a good place to start out. You might need to scroll down a bit further to find videos that talk about terrestrial planets and moons.

Comment: It may be such that a large moon formed in the same way as Luna is hypothesized. may be impossible for a larger mass planet. That is a plausible how a moon got there may be hard; but a moon existing in orbit around a super Earth in terms of stable orbit is an easy yes.

Comment: How is it impossible around a larger mass planet? Also it did form similar to Luna seeing as it was formed when the system was still a chaotic mess

Comment: Is the scientific accuracy relevant to the story? I of course understand it is a nice bonus, but people are willing to suspend belief for a story.

Comment: Yea im planning for the story to be scientifically accurate

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

Do you need a simple proof? You just need to know two concepts beforehand :

- A [super-Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Earth) is different from Earth by... Well, being super. [It's heavier than Earth](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/what-is-an-exoplanet/planet-types/super-earth/), and lighter than gas giants.
- Gravity and mass is the main factor to hold a moon. Higher gravity and higher mass means the moon will have a lesser impact when moving the main planet around.

[image: An animation showing two planets circling around each other. One is very big, the other is very small. The small planet still impacts the big one's orbit, making it move in small circles.]
<sup>An heavier planet relatively to the moon means that its orbit will get less affected, giving a moon-like orbit. You can look what happens if you shift the planets's "weight" here : [Barycenter in astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter_(astronomy)). By Zhatt, public domain, from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit4.gif).</sup>

With these concepts in mind, let's take a look at our solar system!

- Take Earth : It has the moonest of the moons, the Moon .
- Then take [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn), our nice very big gas giant : It has many natural satellites of various sizes. It also has an huge moon, [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)), which is much larger than Earth's one.

Your super-Earth's mass is between two planets which are very capable of holding moons. Since mass is a critical condition to keep around a satellite of significant size<sup>1</sup>, a super-Earth could therefore capture and hold a moon in its orbit.

Now, it is trickier to know the maximum size of the moon before it is not considered a planet/moon couple, but two planets dancing a Viennese waltz instead. Still, due to the increased mass, it's very reasonable to expect at least an Earth's Moon sized moon, if not more. For the exact size, it will be dependent on the exact properties of your planet and your moon.

---

---

<sup>1 : ie. not an asteroid, the ISS, [a car](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-42992143)...</sup>

Comment: The moon would be about the size of our moon

Comment: @JerryRobinson That's what I thought indeed ^^. I wouldn't have dared to give you a small rock that's not even worth a look in the telescope.

Comment: Yea i wouldn't have a small moon anyways

Comment: I wonder what kind of orbit would suggest a waltz, which by definition is in triple time.

Comment: The moment the center of orbit between the two objects, the barycenter, resides outside the radius of both objects they are no longer considered planet moon but a double planet.... that is if the other criteria of planethood are met.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of natural satellites or moons in our solar system.

Regular moons formed in orbit around their planets much like planets formed in orbit around the Sun.

Irregular moons formed elsewhere in the solar system and happened to be captured by the planets which they now orbit.

The four giant planets in our solar system have hundreds of regular and irregular moons orbiting them.

The four terrestrial planets in our solar system have only three moons orbiting them.  But it is likely there were originally more moons.

A moon can only have a long term by astronomical standards stable orbit around a planet if it orbits within a planet's hills sphere (in fact, only within the inner third or half of the Hill sphere).   If a moon orbits beyond the inner part of the Hill sphere it or beyond the Hill sphere it is likely to eventually escape frm orbit around the planet to orbit around the Sun.

The radius of the Hill sphere around a planet is calculated from the mass of the planet, the mass of the star, the eccentricity of the planet's orbit, and the semi-major axis of the planet's orbit.  The less massive a planet is, and the closer it is to its star, the smaller its Hill radius will be.

The formula for a planet's Hill radius can be found at:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04860)

And there are probably online calculators for it.

A moon with a stable orbit must orbit its planet within the inner part of the Hill radius, but also outside the Roche limit where it will be broken up by tidal interaction with the planet.  So the Roche limit is sort of the roach motel bug traps; satellites enter but they don's survive.

The formula for a planet's Roche limit can be found at:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Pluto#Origin)

And there are probably online calculators for it.

Another property of the orbits of moons is their direction and also their distance relative to the synchronous orbital distance.

Regular moons and many irregular moons orbit their planets in the prograde direction, the same direction as the planet rotates.  Tidal interactions between planets and prograde moons orbiting above the synchronous orbital distance slowly push the moons farther from the planets.

Tidal interactions between planets and prograde moons orbiting below the synchronous orbital distance slowly pull the moons closer to from the planets.  It is calculated that Phobos should crash into Mars in tens of millions of year.

Many irregular moons orbit their planets in the retrograde direction, opposite to the direction the planet rotates. Tidal interactions between planets and retrograde moons slowly pull the moon closer to the planets.  It is calculated that Triton should crash into Neptune in a few billion years.

Mercury and Venus are less massive than Earth and closer to the Sun, So their Hill spheres are much smaller than Earth's.  Mercury and Venus also rotate very slowly and have very long rotation periods.  Thus their synchronous orbits are far beyond their Hill Spheres.

Any moons they had beyond their Hill spheres would have been lost into interplanetary space, while any moons they had within their Hills spheres would have been far below the synchronous orbits and crashed into them long ago.

So only two terrestrial planets in our solar system, Earth and Mars, could have kept any regular moons they formed.

The two small moons of Mars might not be regular moons formed when Mars was formed.
They might be captured asteroids or debris from a collision between Mars and another object, for example.

To be continued.

How massive could the largest moons of a giant planet - a planet many times as massive as a super Earth - be?

> Canup & Ward (2006) have shown that moons formed in the circumplanetary disk of giant planets have masses ≲10-4 times that of the planet’s mass.

[https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor-planet_moon#List_of_minor_planets_with_moons)

https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04860

10-4 means 1/10,000 or 0.0001.

So if a super Earth has between 2 and 10 times the mass of Earth, the most massive moon which could form in a circumplanetary disc around should have a mass of 0.0002 to 0.001 the mass of Earth.

But the Earth, which has a mass of 1.0 Earth, has moon orbiting it, the Moon with a mass of 0.0123 that of Earth, which is 123 times as massive as that limit.  So perhaps terrestrial planets are not subject to the forces which limit the relative masses of the satellite systems of giant planets.

In any case, the Moon is now not believed to be a regular satellite, formed in a circumplanetary disc as Earth was forming.

The theory for the last few decades has been that billions of years ago, before the early solar system was stabilized, a dwarf planet roughly the size of Mars had an orbit similar to Earth's orbit.  And that is not a long term stable orbital configuration.  So after a few million years or so that planet, call Theia, collided with the Earth.  Much matter from Earth and Theia was thrown into space, some of that matter formed a ring in orbit around the Earth, and some of that eventually formed the Moon.

If the interactions between Theia and other planets were different, it might have missed the Earth and fallen into the Sun or been ejected from the solar system.  Or if Earth already had one or more large moons when Theia passed by, gravitational interactions could have flung those moons away into space while capturing Theia into orbit around the Earth.

I don't know how probable it would have been for Theia to be captured into orbit around Earth as compared with falling into the Sun, being ejected from the solar system, or colliding with Earth and making a moon of Earth from fragments.

But I guess that would happen sometimes in some star systems.

The dwarf planet Pluto has five moons.  Pluto has a radius of about 1,188.3 kilometers and a mass of 0.00218 Earths, while its largest moon, Charon, has a radius of about 606 kilometers and a mass of 0.000266 Earth, about one eighth the mass of Pluto.

Pluto and Charon are sometimes considered to be a double dwarf planet system.

> It is suspected that Pluto's satellite system was created by a massive collision, similar to the "big whack" thought to have created the Moon.[29][30] In both cases, the high angular momenta of the moons can only be explained by such a scenario. The nearly circular orbits of the smaller moons suggests that they were also formed in this collision, rather than being captured Kuiper Belt objects. This and their near orbital resonances with Charon (see below) suggest that they formed closer to Pluto than they are at present and migrated outward as Charon reached its current orbit. Their grey color is different from that of Pluto, one of the reddest bodies in the Solar System. This is thought to be due to a loss of volatiles during the impact or subsequent coalescence, leaving the surfaces of the moons dominated by water ice. However, such an impact should have created additional debris (more moons), yet no moons or rings were discovered by New Horizons, ruling out any more moons of significant size orbiting Pluto.[1](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04860)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Pluto#Origin

The largest irregular moon in the solar system, Triton, is more massive than all other irregular moons of the giant planets combined.  It has a retrograde orbit which proves that it was captured.

The mass of Triton is 0.00359 Earth, which is 0.000209366 of the mass of Neptune, 17.147 Earth.  The radius of Triton is 1,353.4 kilometers, 0.0549 of the radius of Neptune, 24,622 kilometers.   Triton is the second largest satellite in our solar system, relative to its planet, after the Moon.  The mass of Triton is about twice the mass of the entire system of regular moons that a gas planet with Neptune's mass should form.

to be continued.

Many asteroids have companion asteroids.  Usually one asteroid is much larger than the other, making the smaller asteroid more or less a "moon"of the larger asteroid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor-planet_moon#List_of_minor_planets_with_moons

Sometimes the two asteroids have similar size, making them double asteroids.

90 Antiope is a good example of a double asteroid.  The two parts of 90 Antiope have diameters of about 88 and84 kilometers, and differ in mass by less than 2.5 percent.  Thus they can be considered "twin" asteroids.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90_Antiope

So many asteroids have moons which are very much smaller than them, while some asteroids have companions which are approximately their twins.

> Several dwarf planet candidates can be described as binary planets. At its 2006 General Assembly, the International Astronomical Union considered a proposal that Pluto and Charon be reclassified as a double planet,[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90_Antiope) but the proposal was abandoned in favor of the current IAU definition of planet. Other dwarf systems with proportionally large planetary mass satellites include Eris–Dysnomia, Orcus–Vanth and Ilmarë–Varda.
>
> Binary asteroids with components of roughly equal mass are sometimes referred to as double minor planets. These include binary asteroids 69230 Hermes and 90 Antiope and binary Kuiper belt objects (KBOs) 79360 Sila–Nunam and 1998 WW31.

So there are a number small solar systems objects which are doubles with approximately the same mass, and some larger dwarf planets and dwarf planet candidates which are doubles with approximately the same mass.

So:
The moons of asteroids are usually much smaller than their primaries, but sometimes closer to the same size, and sometimes an asteroid pair can approximately equal in size and  be considered a double asteroid.

Sometimes large objects in the outer solar system, dwarf planets or candidates to be considered dwarf planets, have large enough companions that they can be considered double dwarf planets.

Terrestrial planets can lose their moons if they are too close to the Sun, but are known to have two small probably captured moons and one large moon considered to be formed from debris of giant impact.

Super Earths would be terrestrial planets much larger than the Earth or any terrestrial planets in our solar system, but smaller than giant planets.

Gas giant and ice giant planets have many tiny moons and a number of medium sized moons and a few very large moons.  Most of the large moons are regular moons, but one is an irregular captured moon.

Judging from this progression from the smallest objects to the largest objects in our solar system, it seems logical to guess that many super Earth planets wouldn't have any moons, and others might have only a few tiny captured moons.  Some should have regular moons of various sizes. Some should have small, medium, or large captured moons.  Some should have small, medium, or large moons formed from giant impacts.

And although smaller moons would probably be more common than larger moons, some super Earths should have companion worlds large enough to be considered double planets instead of a planet and moon.

I quoted only one sentence from the following discussion earlier:

> The largest and most massive moon in the Solar System, Ganymede, has a radius of only ≈0.4R⊕ (R⊕ being the radius of
> Earth) and a mass of ≈0.025M⊕. The question as to whether much more massive moons could have formed around
> extrasolar planets is an active area of research. Canup & Ward (2006) have shown that moons formed in the circumplanetary disk of giant planets have masses ≲10-4 times that of the planet’s mass. Assuming satellites formed around
> Kepler-22b, their masses will thus be 2.5×10-3M⊕ at most, and around KOI211.01 they will still weigh less than Earth’s
> Moon. Mass-constrained in situ formation becomes critical for exomoons around planets in the IHZ of low-mass stars
> because of the observational lack of such giant planets. An excellent study on the formation of the Jupiter and the Saturn
> satellite systems is given by Sasaki et al. (2010), who showed that moons of sizes similar to Io, Europa, Ganymede, Callisto,
> and Titan should build up around most gas giants. What is more, according to their Fig. 5 and private communication with
> Takanori Sasaki, formation of Mars- or even Earth-mass moons around giant planets is possible. Depending on whether or
> not a planet accretes enough mass to open up a gap in the protostellar disk, these satellite systems will likely be multiple and
> resonant (as in the case of Jupiter), or contain only one major moon (see Saturn). Ogihara & Ida (2012) extended these
> studies to explain the compositional gradient of the jovian satellites. Their results explain why moons rich in water are
> farther away from their giant host planet and imply that capture in 2:1 orbital resonances should be common.
>
> Ways to circumvent the impasse of insufficient satellite mass are the gravitational capture of massive moons (Debes &
> Sigurdsson 2007; Porter & Grundy 2011; Quarles et al. 2012), which seems to have worked for Triton around Neptune
> (Goldreich et al. 1989; Agnor & Hamilton 2006); the capture of Trojans (Eberle et al. 2011); gas drag in primordial circumplanetary envelopes (Pollack et al. 1979); pull-down capture trapping temporary satellites or bodies near the Lagrangian
> points into stable orbits (Heppenheimer & Porco 1977; Jewitt & Haghighipour 2007); the coalescence of moons (Mosqueira
> & Estrada 2003); and impacts on terrestrial planets (Canup 2004; Withers & Barnes 2010; Elser et al. 2011). Such moons
> would correspond to the irregular satellites in the Solar System, as opposed to regular satellites that form in situ. Irregular
> satellites often follow distant, inclined, and often eccentric or even retrograde orbits about their planet (Carruba et al. 2002).
> For now, we assume that Earth-mass extrasolar moons – be they regular or irregular – exist.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf

And sometimes some of the methods listed might enable a super Earth to acquire a really large moon.

I see that the question also asks whether the strong  gravity of a super Earth would pull down a large moon.

The giant planets in our solar system, which have much stronger gravity than super Earth's, have many moons which have been orbiting them for billions of years without crashing into the surface.

I have already explained above the orbital factors which will make a moon gradually move farther from or closer to its planet.

Comment: The Moon is receding from Earth and ~1.5 inches / year. Phobos is spiraling in toward Mars and only has about 50M/yrs before it breaks up / crashes. Demos is moving away from Mars.  Are any moons actually stable? Is there any accepted definition of an astronomically stable moon?

Comment: @Gillgamesh at the rate the amoon is receding, and consodering how long she's been with us, I would call her relstionship with Earth quite stable.